# Unable to redirect to next page

Tags: php

```
form method="POST" action="myprofile.php" id='myformid<?=$userid?>' name="myprof">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?=$userid?>" name="id">

                <a  onClick="document.getElementById('myformid<?=$userid?>').submit();" style="cursor:pointer"><?=ucfirst($fname)." ".ucfirst($lname)?>
            </a>


</form>
```

I am using form and from current page I want to get redirected to myprofile.php but its not working.
To cross check the code when I use alert in anchor tag as below

```
<a  onClick="alert(document.getElementById('myformid<?=$userid?>'))" style="cursor:pointer"><?=ucfirst($fname)." ".ucfirst($lname)?>
                </a>
```

it returns null value...
Can anyone suggest me any solution or what is going wrong ?

Comment: <form is missing the leading <, assuming you have cut and pasted your example correctly

Comment: I apologize for this but by mistake its missing leading < but in actual I have used leading <

Comment: Okay, I tested the above snippet and it works just fine for me. Have you tried placing the above in its own PHP file and confirming it works? Is there anything else on your page that might be causing the issue? Did you post all the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the code with this if you want to submit the form without anchor tag

```
<form method="POST" action="myprofile.php" id='myformid<?=$userid?>' name="myprof">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$userid?>" name="id">
    <input type="submit" value= "<?=ucfirst($fname).' '.ucfirst($lname)?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code and it also works fine on my machine:

```
<?php $userid=12; $fname="hans"; $lname="meier"; ?>

<form method="POST" action="myprofile.php" id='myformid<?=$userid?>' name="myprof">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$userid?>" name="id">
    <a  onClick="document.getElementById('myformid<?=$userid?>').submit();" style="cursor:pointer"><?=ucfirst($fname)." ".ucfirst($lname)?></a>             
    <br>
    <a  onClick="alert(document.getElementById('myformid<?=$userid?>'))" style="cursor:pointer"><?=ucfirst($fname)." ".ucfirst($lname)?></a>
</form>
```

First link redirects as you wanted, and the second posts `object HTMLFormElement` just as expected.
Maybe you want to take this code and try it out on your machine, maybe the error is somewhere else than the supplied code.

(sry this was obviously to long for a comment)